# Combine two UART inputs to one averaged UART output?

Tags: microcontroller, uart, gps, controller

My thought with this project was to combine two UART gps receivers to one board that would then average the GPS position and output a UART GPS signal.

I have no idea if this is even possible. I've created an ideal layout below.[image]

Comment: So, is your question: "Is this possible?" Note that your title question is quite different to what your description is saying. An average UART signal is something I don't know and not sure about the information content. Reading two GPS positions from two GPS receivers and averaging these positions and output them as one new packet sounds quite possible to me with a small microcontroller.

Comment: Sure it is *possible* in many ways but you did not define how would the data stream should be averaged, i.e merged per character, merged per line, or actually averaging the GPS data to look like single GPS transmitter sent it? Any microcontroller or PC with enough UART can do this, but what is the use for this?

Comment: No, you cannot combine/average UART TX/RX signals like this.

Comment: Why don't you 'average' the data received, on the microcontroller code, instead of 'averaging' the two serial signals.

Comment: @MituRaj my goal with this project to provide a single controller the hobbyist can use to combine the signal from two of the same GPS receivers, without the need to reprogram the individual GPS receiver. I would like to provide a great degree of accuracy for hobbyist drones.

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible as it is ... Seems like you are driving this question to XY Problem.

Answer (score 3):

> ... average UART signal

Um, I don't think you mean what that means, instead you mean:

> ... average the GPS position and output a UART GPS signal

which means you need a microcontroller to interact with your two GPS receivers, do the averaging, and send out a new NMEA message "downstream".

Note, however, that this is *not* a good idea, usually. If you've got one receiver that has better view of the sky than the other, then it's very likely the "worse" one will make your average GPS coordinate worse than only looking at the better one would.

A simple solution would be having the same microcontroller, and reading the estimate standard deviation from the NMEA messages, and only forwarding these messages that have better (read: lower) variance.

Even better, probably, would be implementing an algorithm that tracks these two, and then calculates a sensibly fusioned position estimate. But that might be relatively involved!

Comment: Yes, your completely correct. I think you understand what I'm trying to do. My goal is to be able to include two gps units on a single drone without needing to modify the flight controller firmware to accept two different GPS UART signals. So for example I would be able to install two GPS units on the drone, somehow combine the signals to gain a higher level of accuracy, and then send that final signal to a single UART on the FC that would think it's one GPS receiver.

Comment: Why would a second receiver on a single drone (assuming that's not like a US Predator drone) be better than a single one? That's usually not very much how it works..

Comment: @Karekin_FPV No, your goal/problem is: to get high accuracy in GPS. Marcus has provided you a solution. Don't make this an XY problem.